# Как передать интент из сервиса в АКтивность

Tags: java, android

Есть сервис который вызывает уведомление, при нажатии на уведомление должна открыться активность и должно передаваться значение из сервиса

В сервисе:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,ActivityFragments.class);
intent.putExtra("ExamFragment","ExamFragment");
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,0);
```

В активности:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String value = intent.getStringExtra("ExamFragment"); // there is null
```

Почему приходит `null`?

Comment: Вы из сервиса хотите запустить активити и передать ей данные?

Comment: @post_zeew да,верно

Comment: @post_zeew куда пропали?

Comment: @MartinezToni, вы не ответили в своём предыдущем вопросе - вы данные не в `onNewIntent()` пытаетесь получить?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да, я пытаюсь их получить не в onNewIntent

Comment: @MartinezToni, ну так попробуйте таки в нём.................

Comment: Что-то не получается.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб это пишу в сервисе  Intent intent = new Intent(this,ActivityFragments.class);
        intent.putExtra("ExamFragment","ExamFragment");
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,0);

Comment: @ЮрийСПб это пишу в активности    @ Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        intent = getIntent();
        String value = intent.getStringExtra("ExamFragment");
        }

Comment: @ЮрийСПб ну и что скажете?

Comment: @MartinezToni, выглядит как рабочий код

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да вот не работает-ничего не приходит(даже Null не приходит),  а если пишу код в onCreate, то при нажатии на уведомление перехожу на активность, активность достает intent, умирает , пересоздается и в итоге null

Что делать?

Comment: Может у вас манифесте флаг какой-то стоит и мешает? И попробуйте PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT последним аргументом при создании PengigIntent

Comment: Флагов в манифесте нет
Только вот это  android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"

Comment: @ЮрийСПб поставил флаг, все равно такая же ситуация. Активность пересоздается

Answer (score 1):

Когда Activity перезапускается, то используется уже существующий инстанс, которому просто передается новый Intent. В этом случае запускается метод 
onNewIntent(). Проверьте ваши данные в нём.